Boosting amplitude of IMPLY gate
Here is IMPLY gate truth table:

And here is my circuit:

It returned expected output:

Since, 0xx is my solution, how do I boost that amplitude. I know that I should have use Grover Algorithm. But I don't know how to implement it.
Update:
@diemilio IMPLY gate is same like OR/AND which is irreversible that require ancilla qubit to operate, the output of IMPLY. The idea is, suppose that I don't know what type of truth table is, but I only know the output set. and that function accept two input (two qubit). Then I noticed anomaly the output is 0 at a point. That's the question, I need to find in what point (input combination) that the function returning 0. This is why I put Hadamard Gate so that both inputs are in superposition. I marked the answer is on MSB (Most Significanf Bit/Leftest Bit) must be equal 0. That's why I said 0xx. The xx I pretend to don't know what combination input is it. (In this case, the answer has been found which is 001 which means A=1, B=0, OUT=0.
In another word, I need to nullify any probabilities that returning (1xx) which is 100, 101, 110, 111. And Boostig any probabilities that returning (0xx) which is 000,001,010,011. Only 001` has highest probability while the others zero, which means it must be amplified and the others keep down.

Your question is not very clear. You say you want to amplify state 001, but what does that have to do with the IMPLY gate? Maybe try to add some context to your question to clarify what is it that you are trying to accomplish.

@diemilio I added my clarification

What you need to do is use the IMPLY gate to construct the oracle used in Grover's algorithm.
First off, you need to fix the implementation of your gate. It might look like it is working correctly because you are performing measurements of the inputs before applying the gate, but for it work, you need to make sure your inputs a and b are uncomputed after the $CCX$ gate:

Next, what you want to do is use this circuit as your oracle. So you want to place your inputs a and b in equal superposition, and register c initialized to the $|-\rangle$ state. Now, the issue here is that phase kickback (which marks your state) works when the qubit on c is equal to 1, but your circuit actually gives the answer you want when c is 0. Fortunately, this is easy to fix, all you need to do is invert the answer of c by adding an $X$ gate after the IMPLY gate.
To see that the above works, look at the output statevector of this circuit, the $H$ and $X$ gate at the end are to switch back state $|-\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ in the bottom qubit:

This will results in the following state:
$$ \frac{1}{2} |000\rangle+\frac{1}{2} |010\rangle- \frac{1}{2} |100\rangle+\frac{1}{2} |110\rangle $$
which, as you can see, the output you are looking for ($|100\rangle$) has been marked with a minus sign (like the oracle should do).
Next you just add the regular Grover diffuser, and perform measurements:

If you run a simulation, you should get 100% probability of measuring 10 which are the values of a and b that give you an output of 0 for the IMPLY gate.
Here's the statevector you will have after each step of the circuit:

Initialize state:

$$ |\psi_0 \rangle = |000 \rangle $$

Place a and b in equal superposition, and c in the $|-\rangle$ state:

$$ |\psi_1 \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle + |11\rangle \right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle\right) $$
Expanding this state:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|\psi_1 \rangle = &\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |100\rangle + |110\rangle \right) -
\\
& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|001\rangle + |011\rangle + |101\rangle + |111\rangle \right) 
\end{aligned}
$$
Then we apply the IMPLY gate, which you know how it works when c starts at |0\rangle. For the cases where c is $|1\rangle$ (second part of the superposition above) you simply get the inverted output:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|\psi_2 \rangle = &\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|001\rangle + |011\rangle + |100\rangle + |111\rangle \right) -
\\
& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |101\rangle + |110\rangle \right) 
\end{aligned}
$$
Next, apply the $X$ gate on c to invert the output:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
|\psi_3 \rangle = &\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|000\rangle + |010\rangle + |101\rangle + |110\rangle \right) -
\\
& \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(|001\rangle + |011\rangle + |100\rangle + |111\rangle \right) 
\end{aligned}
$$
The critical step here is that you can re-factorize the c qubit as the $|-\rangle$ state (this is what phase kickback is all about):
$$ |\psi_3 \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|00\rangle + |01\rangle - |10\rangle + |11\rangle \right) \otimes \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(|0\rangle - |1\rangle\right) $$
Then we apply the $X$ and $H$ gates to c to turn $|-\rangle$ back to $|0\rangle$:
$$ |\psi_4 \rangle = \frac{1}{2}\left(|00\rangle + |01\rangle - |10\rangle + |11\rangle \right) \otimes |0\rangle $$
Lastly, we apply the diffuser on the top 2 qubits, which performs a reflection about the equal-superposition state, leaving only the marked element:
$$ |\psi_5 \rangle =  - |10\rangle \otimes |0\rangle $$
So, performing measurements will result in 100 with 100% probability.

I'm questioning NOT gate in b, why it's specifically added after TOFFOLI?
Can you answer with preserving my defined IMPLY? So there is barrier for it. You might add something before and after barrier of my defined IMPLY. For example to cancel answer C output, you can add NOT gate again. It seems that your answer is simplified version mathematically. I'm hardly to understand it.

the X gate in b after the Toffoli is to uncompute the register. This should not affect the operation of the gate, and guarantees that a and b are the same at the input and output of the gate. Yes, a simple way to "preserve" the IMPLY gate would be to then instead of removing the X gate, is adding another X gate in c right after the gate is applied. Effectively, the two X gates cancel; that's why I removed it. Not sure what you mean by "your answer is simplified version mathematically"; cancelling two X gates in series is a trivial operation.

But the problem is you supposed to not knowing the blackbox function (IMPLY function), that's why I'm still questioning why you unregistered b with NOT gate. You act like you already know what is input output pair so that's why you put NOT gate after TOFFOLI in b.

Perhaps we need if condition.

I am not assuming that. What I'm saying is that your implementation of the IMPLY gate is incorrect. Classically it is fine, but if you try to use it inside a quantum algorithm (like Grover) it will not give you the correct answer. When you add the first X gate in b, you have changed the original state of that qubit, so you need to take that qubit back to its input state. This is known as "uncomputation" and it is critical in pretty much all QC algorithms. In other words, even if I don't know what's inside that gate, whoever constructed it should've taken care of adding that X gate.

I posted my answer for another use case, such as NIMPLY. What do you think? Perhaps you can correct my understanding if there is something wrong.

While @diemilio answer the original question, I tried to answer the NIMPLY:
Here is NIMPLY truth table and its probabilities:

Suppose that we want to find anomaly why the output is 1 while the other output is 0. We can find the causation by bruteforcing all possible input:
NIMPLY 1
And here is circuit for NIMPLY that only works on classical computing perspective but doesn't work for quantum computing:


NIMPLY 2
And here is circuit for NIMPLY that works both on perspective on classical computing and quantum computing:


Quantum Computing Explanation
Both of them has same output when a=0 and b=0 which returning output of 0 (MSB=0), but NIMPLY 1 left the trace after doing computation even though the output is same like NIMPLY 2. The trace is an imbalanced input that expected to be zero for all qubit (a=0 and b=0) but leaving (a=0 and b=1). This is problem for quantum computing but not a problem for classical computation since it only care the output, and the input cannot be recycled.
While the quantum computation recycle the input to process further. In order to to that all phase and magnitude must be in same initial state after processed by blackbox function. It can be seen that the output is (a=0 and b=0) both before computing the function and after computing the function, hence it can be recycled for further processing by quantum computing algorithm (Maybe only by Grover Algorithm for this case).
So, the circuit must be take care of input after designing circuit because it can affect for another algorithm. Unlike classical computation, don't care the input after getting the output:
So here is the Grover Algorithm for NIMPLY, it produce MSB=1 when we didn't know the other bit input.

Returning probability 100% at 101 where 1 (left) is output, 0 is b, and 1 (right) is a, which equivalent like the truth table I mentioned above.

